# How to add extra fields to the activation email?

Tags: user, emails, profile, email-template

I'm trying to edit the Registration email admins get when users sign up. 
I'm using a plugin called www.easy-profile.com which allowed me to add additional fields to the registration that I've called "Company" however it doesn't add these to the email so the admin can see what company the user is signing up with.

I've then tired to add "components/com_users/models/registration.php" $[company] but this breaks the registration form.

Is there a way to get this added?

Easy Profile developer has said the following:
"Hi,
Easy profile extend Joomla user managment but not replace. This email us generated by joomla. And no way to change it.
You can disable this from users configuration and create a simple plugin to do this (require basic PHP knowledge)."

Comment: Please contact the developer of Easy Profile as it's their extension.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, the issue is what the developer came back to me with "Hi,
Easy profile extend Joomla user managment but not replace. This email us generated by joomla. And no way to change it.
You can disable this from users configuration and create a simple plugin to do this (require basic PHP knowledge)."

Answer (score 1):

I will try to answer this, more in a general sense, not specific to easy-profile.

The code responsible to sending the email is located in the [registration](https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/staging/components/com_users/models/registration.php#L75) model. You can hack that, but it would just be the wrong approach. In order to hack it you need to change two things:

- Language string: COM_USERS_EMAIL_ACTIVATE_WITH_ADMIN_ACTIVATION_BODY to include a new string %s what you later provide with sprintf.
- You need to get somehow the data that your extension saves.

Basically it is very hard to customize this without hacking things, as there are no plugins that are called from here.

Another approach would be to replace the whole Joomla mailer. [AcyMailing](https://www.acyba.com/acymailing/362-acymailing-joomlanotification.html) seems to offer something in this direction, I cannot say more.

Answer (score 0):

You can use RSForm component to create a registration form with any fields and customizable welcome email. After this, you can enable registration plugin to include this user information in Joomla like a Registration form;

- https://www.rsjoomla.com/joomla-extensions/rsform.html
- https://www.rsjoomla.com/support/documentation/rsform-pro/plugins-and-modules/rsformpro-joomla-user-registration-plugin.html

See this tutorial video in RSForm site.